# Passing Value when Select on GridView to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView which is showing some data:

> Entity_ID (PK)
>   Name
>   Description

Now I am enabling Select in my GridView. I need to pass Entity_ID to another page and in this page I am showing more contents for this Entity_ID.

How should I pick the Entity_ID value and pass it in as Query String? I have this code:

```
ProductsDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
```

Any responses will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
 protected void gvAgentList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gvAgentList.SelectedRow;
        Response.Redirect("~/FrontEnd/Registration.aspx? EntityID=" + row.Cells[0].Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a new item template column in you grid and add the select link as below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/detailspagename.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("Entity_ID")) %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Its giving me err: This name contains Uppercase Char which is not allowed.

Comment: @klm9971: How you are using this in your page ?

Comment: Is it called this:  <asp:TemplateField>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: @GSGuy: This snippet I am putting it inside <Columns> here </Columns>.

Comment: I have updated the answer for more clarity. Put this tag within columns tag of Gridview.

Comment: @GSGuy: I am getting an err again: Content ('</Columns>') does not match any properties within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField', make sure it is well-formed.

Comment: @GSGuy: Posted another answer. Please check!

Answer (score 1):

Use the OnRowSelected event. Once it calls that you can get the selected row and then the entity id. Next you can build a string with the entity id in the query string and response.redirect to that page.

Comment: There is no event called OnRowSelected. Tried that.

Comment: @klm9971 Yeah, I meant SelectedIndexChanged. OnRowSelected is only available in some third party controls. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

there are several approaches how to pass data between pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

the query string is ok if you don't mind the url will contain the ID

you can also consider Page.PreviousPage from the options above, which seems reasonable in your case

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DataKeys 
set `DataKeys='Entity_ID'`

In the code behind you can access the same as `selectedrow.DataKeys[rowindex]["Entity_ID"]`

here selected row is the one you selected , rowindex the index and you get the corresponding Entity_ID

Answer (score 0):

@GSGuy:

```
<asp:GridView runat ="server" ID = "gvAgentList" 
            AllowPaging = "True" 
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="#E8E8E8" 
            BorderColor="#003399" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="375px" 
            Width="823px"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onselectedindexchanged="gvAgentList_SelectedIndexChanged">


        <AlternatingRowStyle ForeColor="#0066CC" />
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                SortExpression="Description" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/detailspagename.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("Entity_ID")) %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>

        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#3366FF" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
    string fname, lname;
    fname = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    Session["fname"] = fname;
    lname = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    Session["lname"] = lname;
    Response.Redirect("gridpass.aspx");
 }
```

On gridpass.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = Session["fname"].ToString();
   TextBox2.Text = Session["lname"].ToString();
}
```